# Suggest a material which can produce heat with DC current

Tags: materials

Can anyone please suggest me a material which can produce heat with DC current.
I want it to be low of cost.
I should be able to turn it into a sheet.
And if there no such material. Please tell me how i make it. Or what can i use to do so.

Comment: Nichrome wire will get hot if you match resistance to voltage so it gets to a suitable temperature without melting.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much heat you want, what voltage you want to use, and what current.  But pretty much any metal will produce heat when you flow current through it.  Copper, aluminum, iron, steel, take your pick.  Take apart an old hair dryer or a space heater or an electric blanket and see how they do it.  Those are typically designed with AC current, but they could just as easily be re-designed to use DC.  You just have to get the voltage and current right.

Answer (score 0):

sheet heaters have been on the market for years. the cheapest ones use a carbon black-rich paste painted onto a sheet of fireproof paper-like material, onto which is sealed another sheet of the same to protect it. strips of copper tape running along 2 opposite sides of the sheet are used to feed electricity into the carbon black, which gets hot when current flows through it. These heaters are used in foot massage units, yogurt makers, food warmers and waterbed heaters.