# How can i obtain heat from conductive paint using dc current

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials, chemical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

I have been searching for a material that can heat up when we supply dc current.
Many give me a suggestion for use nichrome wires. Or carbon rich paste paint(conductive paint).
I want a sheet of such material(nichrome)
But i couldn't find sheets online or in the stores. So first of all i want to know how can i make A4 size sheet from those wires.?

Second of all is. If i use carbon rich paste paint and apply it to a normal sheet of paper. Will i be able to obtain heat from it by applying dc current.?

I have to apply dc current. I can't apply AC current.

Comment: See this question : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18685/10902

Comment: If you made the effort to properly describe what you really wanted to achieve we would not be wasting our time...

Comment: AC/DC makes no difference here. You do of course need to have careful control of the voltage you apply.

Comment: buy a waterbed heater and take it apart.

Answer (score 3):

If you end up with something that conducts current, it will heat up with applied current.  One way or another, you have what is called a *resistor*.  A resistor dissipates power proportional to the square of the applied voltage or current.

The trick is to find a material that ends up causing a convenient resistance.  A metal sheet might be so low in resistance that you end up dissipating more power in the connections and the circuit that makes the current than in the sheet itself.  Conversely, if you end up with too high a resistance, it would take too much voltage to get a meaningful amount of heat.

The first thing you should do is create a spec of how much power the whole sheet should dissipate.  That will give you a rough range of total end to end resistance you want.  The power dissipated by a resistor is:

W = A<sup>2</sup> Ω = V<sup>2</sup>/Ω

where W is the power in Watts, A the current in Amperes, V the EMF in Volts, and Ω the resistance in Ohms.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, If you google "nichrome sheet", the very first hit is http://www.goodfellow.com/E/Nickel-Chromium-Sheet.html, which will sell you nichrome sheets in several different thicknesses and sizes. None of the options is quite A4 size, but it's at least close.

For your second question, it is very unclear what you are asking.  How much heat do you want (watts or BTU/hr, etc)?  What temperature do you want the surface of the sheet to get to?  Do you have limitations on the power supply or can you use literally any DC voltage and current? Do you care if the paper catches on fire? As I said in the answer to your original question, basically anything in the world will heat up if you pass enough current through it, so the literal answer to your question is "yes", but I suspect that this is not a useful answer.  If you can describe your application in more detail, we can give you a more helpful/useful answer.